# Issue in GitHub deploy to dev server after GitHub updates

Tags: github, ssh, github-actions, ssh-keys

**Overview:**
We have a script that deploys our branch to the dev server so each branch has a specific URL. Previously, it worked by creating a folder with the branch name in the dev server directory and then populating that folder with the respective UI and API code folders. However, the script no longer works after a recent update from GitHub. While the folder for the branch is still being created, the UI and API folders are now empty.

**Below are the steps I have tried:**

Please find below our `.server_deploy.sh file`. In order to find out where the code stopped executing, I tried adding echo statements. After checking, I discovered that it creates the UI and API folders by running `mkdir api` and `mkdir UI` for the API and UI projects, but no files or folders get deployed by running the following cloning commands.

` #!/bin/bash

```
set -e

echo "Deploying application ..... branch = $1"

#rm -rf "/var/www/html/devserver/$1"

BRANCH_DIR="/var/www/html/devserver/$1"

if [ ! -d "$BRANCH_DIR" ]
then
        mkdir -p "$BRANCH_DIR"
        chown $USER:www-data -R $BRANCH_DIR
        cd $BRANCH_DIR
        echo "Cloning API Repo..."
        mkdir api
        git config --global --add safe.directory $BRANCH_DIR/api
        git clone git@github.com:{API URL HERE} api
        echo "Cloning UI Repo..."
        mkdir ui
        git config --global --add safe.directory $BRANCH_DIR/ui
        git clone git@github.com:{UI URL HERE} ui
        chown $USER:www-data -R $BRANCH_DIR
fi

# back to home directory
cd

# setup Node version
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm use 12.16.3

# setup API
cd $BRANCH_DIR/api

chmod 777 -R storage bootstrap/cache
chown aqib:www-data -R $BRANCH_DIR

#switch branch
git stash
git reset --hard origin/master
git pull
if git branch -a | grep $1
then
    git checkout $1
else
    git checkout master 
fi

cp /var/www/html/devserver/.env $BRANCH_DIR/api/
sed -i -e "s/BRANCH/$1/g" $BRANCH_DIR/api/.env

composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader

php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan migrate --force
php artisan db:seed
php artisan optimize

npm install
npm run prod

#setup UI
cd $BRANCH_DIR/ui

#switch branch
git stash
git reset --hard origin/master
git pull
if  git branch -a | grep $1
then
        git checkout $1
else
        git checkout master
fi

cp /var/www/html/devserver/config.js $BRANCH_DIR/ui/src/api/
sed -i -e "s/BRANCH/$1/g" $BRANCH_DIR/ui/src/api/config.js

npm install
npm run build
```

Also, I tried cloning the branch on the server using ssh and it didn't work. I also added permission to the folder.

Here is our laravel.yml file.

```
name: Laravel

on:
  pull_request

jobs:
  devserver:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      # mysql-service Label used to access the service container
      mysql-service:
        # Docker Hub image (also with version)
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          ## Accessing to Github secrets, where you can store your configuration
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ******
          MYSQL_DATABASE: db_test
        ## map the "external" 33306 port with the "internal" 3306

    ** REST OF THE CODE HERE, LIKE UNIT TESTING AND CODE QUALITY **


    - name: Deploy to Devserver
      env:
        PUSHED_BRANCH_NAME: ${{ steps.branch-name.outputs.head_ref_branch }}
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DEVSERVER_SSH_USER }}
        host: ${{secrets.DEVSERVER_HOST}}
        envs: PUSHED_BRANCH_NAME
        password: ${{ secrets.DEVSERVER_SSH_PASS }}
        script: sudo /home/$USER/.server_deploy.sh $PUSHED_BRANCH_NAME
```

Below are the log of errros which I'm getting while deploying the code to the dev server.

`======CMD======`

`sudo /home/***/.server_deploy.sh $PUSHED_BRANCH_NAME`

`======END======`

`out: Deploying application ..... branch = lg-30rvkhp`

`out: Now using node v12.16.3 (npm v6.14.4)`

`err: chmod: cannot access 'storage': No such file or directory`

`err: chmod: cannot access 'bootstrap/cache': No such file or directory`

`2023/03/27 07:45:20 Process exited with status 1`

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Where are `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` being created here? Your script should create `$BRANCH_DIR/ui` and `$BRANCH_DIR/api`, but there's nothing there to indicate that `~/storage` or `~/bootstrap/cache` should exist.

Comment: @JimRedmond, I have updated my code in the question above so that you can get a better idea. It shows an empty directory because cloning is not working in the script file. However, when I enter the git clone command in the server, it works there. Your help would be greatly appreciated since I am a beginner in this field.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to clone your project? Is this working

```
echo "Cloning API Repo..."
sudo mkdir api
git config --global --add safe.directory $BRANCH_DIR/api
git clone git@github.com:{API URL HERE} api
```

Comment: No, cloning is not working in the server script file. However, when I enter the git clone command in the server, it works using a token.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your output goes from the first "Deploying application" string to the NVM "Now using" response, but it doesn't include the "Cloning API Repo" or "Cloning UI Repo" echoes that should otherwise be between the two (along with the detailed output of the clone tasks). Unless you're obscuring parts of the output, I suspect the problem is in that `if [ ! -d "$BRANCH_DIR" ]` conditional; that test is returning false, so the clone commands are never called in the first place.

Also, how exactly did your SSH cloning attempts "not work"?

Comment: If block will be executed for the very first time when the PR is raised which means the git clone is not working. If we re-run the jobs, it executes the else block as if block already created a branch folder. In the case else, it wouldn't find the storage or bootstrap folder, which throws the mentioned error. The script was working fine until March 23 when it started failing after Github released its updates.

Comment: I think the issue is in the known_hosts. For some reason, it's not authenticating with GitHub. Also, we followed this document: https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/

Comment: In addition, when I manually clone the repo and re-run the jobs, it executes the else statement and throws the following error:

Comment: ======CMD======
sudo /home/***/.server_deploy.sh $PUSHED_BRANCH_NAME
======END======
out: Deploying application ..... branch = lg-85zrh1tgu
out: Now using node v12.16.3 (npm v6.14.4)
out: Saved working directory and index state WIP on lg-85zrh1tgu: b697a67f lg-85zrh1tgu
out: HEAD is now at bdfde0e3 Merge pull request #582 from gitRepoUser/release-2-30-2
err: Host key verification failed.
err: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
err: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
err: and the repository exists.
2023/03/31 07:28:05 Process exited with status 1

Comment: `known_hosts` is managed per user - all users on that system who want to interact with GitHub, including but not limited to the account that runs the script, will need to update their own `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. You can test `known_hosts` fixes with `ssh -T git@github.com`.

If you're re-running this with the same params after a failed clone, then your script will keep failing in the same place. You should either update the script to accommodate failed clones, or delete the failed clone and try again (after fixing known_hosts).

Comment: Initially, this ssh -T git@github.com command failed with an error: public key denied, but we fixed it by updating the keys and generating a new rsa_pub file that we updated on GitHub. After that, the error was resolved. We are able to run commands manually on the development server, and they work, but the code in the script_deploy file does not work.  If we update the script in this case, it throws this error:

**err: Host key verification failed.**
**err: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.**
**err: Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repo exists**

Comment: Which account runs that script? Have you fixed its known_hosts file?

Comment: I tried running the PR from the repository owner's account and it still throws the same error. Additionally, I have updated my known_hosts by following the GitHub article shared above.

Comment: I have not fixed it for all users just the repository owner. I tried to re-run jobs from repository owner's account and it gives me the same error